# Using the same custom methods in almost all my scripts

Tags: java, android, methods

I'm working on a project and I've noticed that I need to copy and paste the same custom methods in almost all my scripts. Is it wrong what I'm doing? I'm duplicating it over and over. Any help is much appreciated.

Sample:

```
public class EventHome extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /********************************************************************
    * SHORTENED TOAST                                                   *
    *********************************************************************/
    public void showToast(String value){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    /********************************************************************
    * SHORTENED ALERTDIALOG                                             *
    *********************************************************************/
    public void showAlert(String title, String btn_txt, String message){
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(EventHome.this);
        alert.setTitle(title).setMessage(message)
        .setNeutralButton(btn_txt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   alert.setCancelable(true);
        }}).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a helper class (lets say **Helper**) and move all your repetitive methods in that class file with access modifier as `public static`. Doing so will allow you to call the methods together with class name as prefix. See below:

```
public class Helper{

    /********************************************************************
    * SHORTENED TOAST                                                   *
    *********************************************************************/
    public static void showToast(Context context, String value){
        Toast.makeText(context, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

now call the following in your activities when you want to show toast:

```
Helper.showToast(this, "hello world!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use library project and put such methods and classes in it.  See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) for more info about managing android library projects

Answer (score 1):

There is a principle know as [D.R.Y](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY): **Don't Repeat Yourself**.

It is not useful, and is error prone, to repeat code. If you wish to amend a behaviour in the repeated code then it must be modified in all copies of the code. This is error prone as it is easy for the code to become out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly out of context code so it's hard to give you a definitive answer but the general principal remains the same: DO NOT REPEAT CODE. You should aim to eliminate all forms of repetition in code, especially when dealing with hardcoded values. Common ways of doing this are to provide static functions in some other class, or create a superclass which contains all the core functionality that you'll repeatedly need. Below is a brief example of how to use `inheritance` and `abstract classes` to minimize repetition of code:

i.e

```
abstract class CoreMethods extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /********************************************************************
    * SHORTENED TOAST                                                   *
    *********************************************************************/
    public void showToast(String value){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    /********************************************************************
    * SHORTENED ALERTDIALOG                                             *
    *********************************************************************/
    public void showAlert(String title, String btn_txt, String message){
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(EventHome.this);
        alert.setTitle(title).setMessage(message)
        .setNeutralButton(btn_txt, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   alert.setCancelable(true);
        }}).show();
    }

}
```

Save that in a file called CoreMethods.java or something similar. Then, whenever you need those methods you can simply inherit the CoreMethods class and access the functions.

```
public class ExampleClass extends CoreMethods
{
     private void foo() {
         super.showToast("bar");
         super.showAlert("foobar");
     }
}
```

For more information about inheritance in Java, see [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/language/inheritance.shtml)

Comment: I've already extended an Activity, so do I need to inherit it or something?

Comment: I'm a little confused over the hierarchy of your classes at the moment, you haven't provided any information about the class itself. Would you be able to edit the question and provide a skeleton of the class definition you're using?

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that, I'll be editing it soon. Thanks anyway. +1

Comment: Okay, I'm a bit rusty with my Java but you should be able to inherit the `Activity class` and implement the `OnClickListener interface` from your CoreMethods class. I'll edit my answer.